# Issue with java.util.Date.getTime()

Tags: date, simpledateformat

I've a doubt about the java `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`.

I have an application, which maintains its file creation time in **GMT** in the format **`yearMonthDayHourMinute`**. Currently I am in a different TimeZone (say `IST`). So I want to do all my processing in the `GMT` format.

Following snippet shows, how I retrieved convert the date which is stored in my object in to TimeInMillis.

```
>        1. SimpleDateFormat valueSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
>        2. valueSDF.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
>        3. Date date = valueSDF.parse("201212060915");
>        4. System.out.println("date.getTime():  "+ date.getTime());   // returns 1354785300000
>        5. String fileCreationTime= Long.toString((date.getTime()/1000));
>        6. System.out.println("time :: "+ fileCreationTime);   // returns 1354785300
```

The retrieved value in time in millis (step #4) is having an **extra three trailing zeros**. What my application needs is the result divided by 1000.(step #5)

I am curious to know, why date.getTime() appends more number of zeros to the results.
Stack experts, please share your suggestions !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am curious to know, why date.getTime() appends more number of zeros to the results.

It doesn't. It gives the number of *milliseconds* since the Unix epoch. If you need the number of *seconds* since the Unix epoch of January 1st 1970, midnight UTC, you need to divide by 1000. If you want milliseconds (as you claim) then don't divide by 1000. That's all there is to it - it's behaving exactly as intended.

It's not clear why you thinking it's "adding" three zeroes, but I can assure you that it's not. Note that 1354785300 milliseconds would only be 376 *hours* since the Unix epoch...

The date you've given (December 6th 2012, 9:15am in UTC) *is* 1354785300000 milliseconds since the Unix epoch. Why do you expect a result of 1354785300?

> What my application needs is the result divided by 1000

That's incompatible with your claim that it needs milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks John for the quick response. Our application needs exactly the **milliseconds** not **seconds**. If you could try running the above snippet, you can see the variance.

Comment: @RRP: Well I can see the difference because you're dividing by 1000! But if you want milliseconds, you *shouldn't* divide by 1000.

Comment: @John > My application needs the actual milliseconds with out appended by '000' (i.e. 1354785300). So I am forced to divide it by 1000 in order to run my App in the desired way.

Comment: @RRP: That's no longer milliseconds. That's seconds. I don't know how to put it any other way... 1354785300 is the number of *seconds* between the Unix epoch and the date/time you've given. It's *not* the number of milliseconds. Have you done the arithmetic? Can you not see that 1354785300 *milliseconds* is a very small amount of time? (about 15 days)?

Comment: Thanks John for pointing towards the smaller amount of time(15days). Actually it was an issue with my application.

Comment: @RRP: It was fairly clear to me that the problem was *somewhere* on your side, either with the application code or misunderstanding the requirements... glad it's sorted now.